# Instantiate a inherited class using a static method from a base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, class-factory

I have a abstract base class that I have many inherited classes coming off of. What I would like to do is a static member takes in a string, the first class that can parse the string (only one of the inherited classes should be able to) and return a instance of the inherited class.

This is what i am currently doing.

```
public static Epl2Command GenerateCommandFromText(string command)
{
    lock (GenerateCommandFromTextSyncRoot)
    {
        if (!Init)
        {
            Assembly a = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Epl2Command));
            Types = new List<Type>(a.GetTypes());
            Types = Types.FindAll(b => b.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Epl2Command)));
            Init = true;
        }
    }
    Epl2Command ret = null;
    foreach (Type t in Types)
    {

        MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("GenerateCommand", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

        if (method != null)
            ret = (Epl2Command)method.Invoke(null, new object[] { command });
        if (ret != null)
            break;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I would like it so my code would check all inherited classes without having future programmers come back and edit this function when they add more inherited classes.

Is there a way I can force a inherited class to implement their own `GenerateCommand(string)`?

`public static abstract Epl2Command GenerateCommand(string command)` is not valid c#. [Or am I hammering a nail in with a shoe when I should be using a hammer](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx); any better way of doing this class factory would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# does not support static interfaces, so you can't define a static builder method like

```
public interface ICommand
{
    static ICommand CreateCommand(string command);
}
```

I agree with Kevin that you need a Factory pattern. I'll go a step further and say that you need a builder per command type, too. Like this

```
public interface ICommandBuilder
{
    bool CanParse(string input);
    ICommand Build(string input);
}

public interface ICommandBuilder<TCommand> : ICommandBuilder 
    where TCommand : ICommand
{
    TCommand Build(string input);
}
```

Then your factory can accept any input command string, query all builders if they can parse that string, and run Build on the one that can.

```
public interface ICommandFactory
{
    ICommand Build(string input);
}

public class CommandFactory
{
    public ICommand Build(string input)
    {
        var builder = container.ResolveAll(typeof(ICommandBuilder))
            .First(x => x.CanParse(input));
        return builder.Build(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: where did contrainer come from?

Comment: It's pseduo-code, assuming you're using an inversion of control container... Windsor, StructureMap, etc. If you aren't using an IoC, you'll have to find all ICommandBuilder types and instantiate them manually.

Answer (score 0):

What you are eluding to is the Factory Method:

http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFactory.aspx

Here is a link how to implement it.

Comment: Using that pattern requires a different class to be called for each different type of sub-class. I would prefer if I could do it with one factory and it would be smart enough to find all who inherit it and spit out the correct type without editing Epl2Command every time a class is added.